# Как выбрать до 3 карточек, остальные сделать неактивными, все записать в localstorage и при загрузке все выводить как было?

Tags: javascript

Нужно выбирать до 3х карточек. 
При достижении лимита отключаем остальные карточки. 
Карточки по ID записываем в localStorage. И при загрузке страницы расставляем выбор как было.
Проблема в том, что при загрузке не все неактивные карточки становятся неактивными. А также можно выбрать больше ограничения. Казалось бы элементарная задача, а превратилась в нечто невозможное..

jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Vaniljs/19muw4d7/59/

```js
const limit = 3;
var arrForCheckedItem = []; // массив для сохранения el в localStorage

document.addEventListener('click', ({ target: t }) => {
  if (t.classList.contains('product')) {
    if (!t.classList.contains('unchecked')) {
        arrForCheckedItem = []; // обнуляем массив, чтобы не копился
      t.classList.toggle('checked');
      document.querySelectorAll('.product.checked').forEach(i => {
    if (i.classList.contains('checked')) {
            arrForCheckedItem.push(i.dataset.productid); // Сохраняем выбранные el в массив
        }
    })
      localStorage.setItem('checked_items', arrForCheckedItem); // Сохраняем массив в localStorage
      const allChecked = document.querySelectorAll('.product.checked').length >= limit;
      document.querySelectorAll('.product:not(.checked)').forEach(n => {
        n.classList.toggle('unchecked', allChecked);
      });
    }
  }
  console.log(localStorage.getItem('checked_items')); // Проверка содержимого в localStorage
});




// ОТМЕЧАЕМ ВЫБРАННЫЕ И НЕВЫБРАННЫЕ ПРИ ЗАГРУЗКЕ СТРАНИЦЫ

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    let arrFromStorage = localStorage.getItem('checked_items'); // выгружаем данные из localStorage
  let allCards = document.querySelectorAll('.product.slick-slide'); // выбираем все карточки
    if (arrFromStorage.length) { // если localStorage существует
        arrFromStorage.split(',').map(itemFromStorage => { // режем строку из localStorage в массив и перебираем
            allCards.forEach(itemProduct => {
                if (itemProduct.dataset.productid == itemFromStorage) { // если у карточки такой же id - отмечаем ее выбранной
                    itemProduct.classList.add('checked')
                } 
        if (document.querySelectorAll('.product.slick-slide.checked').length >= limit && itemProduct.dataset.productid != itemFromStorage) { // если у карточки не такой же id b выбранных меньше лимита - отмечаем ее не выбранной
                    itemProduct.classList.add('unchecked')
                }
            })
        })
    }
})
```

```css
div:not(.product) {
    display: flex;
}

.product {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 20px;
    background-color: gray;
    border: 2px solid gray;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.product.checked {
    border: 2px solid green;
    background-color: lightgray;
}

.product.unchecked {
    border: 2px solid red;
    background-color: darkgray;
    cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="product slick-slide" data-productid="1">1</div>
  <div class="product slick-slide" data-productid="2">2</div>
  <div class="product slick-slide" data-productid="3">3</div>
  <div class="product slick-slide" data-productid="4">4</div>
  <div class="product slick-slide" data-productid="5">5</div>
  <div class="product slick-slide" data-productid="6">6</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
window._cardsSelector = {
  _f: {},
  defaults: {
    cardsLimit: 3,
    selectors: {
      card: 'div.card'
    }
  }
};

window._cardsSelector._f.save = () => {
  let idList = [];

  $(`${window._cardsSelector.defaults.selectors.card}.selected`)
    .each((i, item) => {
      idList.push($(item).data('card-id'));
    });

  localStorage.setItem('selected_cards', JSON.stringify(idList));
};

window._cardsSelector._f.load = () => {
  let ids = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('selected_cards', '[]'));
  ids.forEach(i => $(`div.card[data-card-id=${i}]`).addClass('selected'));
  window._cardsSelector._f.check();
};

window._cardsSelector._f.check = () => {
  let limit = window._cardsSelector.defaults.cardsLimit,
    defaultSelector = $(`${window._cardsSelector.defaults.selectors.card}.selected`);

  if (defaultSelector.length === limit) {
    $(`${window._cardsSelector.defaults.selectors.card}:not(.selected)`)
      .addClass('disabled');
  } else {
    $(`${window._cardsSelector.defaults.selectors.card}.disabled`)
      .removeClass('disabled');
  }

  window._cardsSelector._f.save();
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  window._cardsSelector._f.load();

  $(window._cardsSelector.defaults.selectors.card)
    .click(function() {
      $(this).toggleClass('selected');
      window._cardsSelector._f.check();
    });
});
```

```css
.cards {
  width: 98% !important;
  margin: 8px auto;
}

.cards>.card {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 150px;
  max-width: 200px;
  padding: 12px;
  margin: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px gray
}

.selected {
  background: rgba(0, 160, 0, 0.07);
}

.disabled {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
}
```

```html
<script class="cssdeck" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="cards">
  <div class="card" data-card-id="1">
    Card Item 1
  </div>
  <div class="card" data-card-id="2">
    Card Item 2
  </div>
  <div class="card" data-card-id="3">
    Card Item 3
  </div>
  <div class="card" data-card-id="4">
    Card Item 4
  </div>
  <div class="card" data-card-id="5">
    Card Item 5
  </div>
  <div class="card" data-card-id="6">
    Card Item 6
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за участие!

Comment: @VanilJS был рад тряхнуть JS-стариной :)

Answer (score 1):

Сделал форк от вашего fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4h0cu1wo/

Мне кажется, что выделение красным стоит сделать с помощью css. Таким образом, можно выделять красным все те, кто не имеет класс `.checked`, но только в случае, если в родителях есть класс `.limit`.

Если в процессе сохранить список с массивом из трех элементов, а потом уменьшить лимит до одного, выделен будет только первый, так как загрузка фактически имитирует последовательные нажатия по карточкам.

index.js:

```
const limit = 3; // Какой лимит выделяемых элементов

let selected = 0; // Количество выделенных на данный момент элементов

const cards = document.getElementById('cards') // Ссылка на контейнер всех карточек
cards.addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {
    if (target.dataset.productid) select(target) // Если нажали по карточке, пытаемся ее выделить
});

window.addEventListener('load', () => load()); // Выполняем загрузку при запуске страницы

// Выделение передаваемого элемента
function select(element) {
    // Если лимит не достигнут или мы нажимаем по выделенному элементу...
    if (selected < limit || element.classList.contains('checked')) {
        element.classList.toggle('checked') // Переключаем .checked
        selected += element.classList.contains('checked') ? 1 : -1 // Если .checked был добавлен, инкрементируем счетчик
        cards.classList.toggle('limit', selected >= limit) // Если достигли лимита, добавляем класс .limit в контейнер
        if (selected >= limit) save() // А так же, при достижении лимита сохраняем полученный список
    }
}

// Сохранение списка выделенных карточек
function save() {
    const items = []
    // Проодим по всем элементам, у которых есть класс .checked
    cards.querySelectorAll('.checked').forEach(element => items.push(element.dataset.productid));
    localStorage.setItem('checked_items', items); // Сохраняем их в LocalStorage
}

// Загрузка списка выделенных карточек
function load() {
  const items = localStorage.getItem('checked_items');
  items.split(',').forEach(id => select(cards.querySelector(`[data-productid="${id}"]`))) // Передаем на выделение карточку с указанным id в dataset
}
```

index.css:

```
div#cards {
  display: flex;
}

.product {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 20px;
  background-color: gray;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  cursor: pointer;
}
  
.limit {
  .product {
    border: 2px solid red;
    background-color: darkgray;

    &:not(.checked) {
      cursor: not-allowed;
    }
  }
}
 
.product.checked {
  border: 2px solid green;
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

index.html:

```
<div id="cards">
  <div class="product slick-slide" data-productid="1">1</div>
  <div class="product slick-slide" data-productid="2">2</div>
  <div class="product slick-slide" data-productid="3">3</div>
  <div class="product slick-slide" data-productid="4">4</div>
  <div class="product slick-slide" data-productid="5">5</div>
  <div class="product slick-slide" data-productid="6">6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за участие!